# Getting Distinct fields from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have 1Million documents which has a field called id.The id field of all the 1Million docs are different.
Eg:`1.id:http://www.bing.com/search?q=malaysia. 2.id:http://www.google.com/search?q=singapore. 3.id:http://www.bing.com/search?q=india. 4.id:http://www.google.com/search?q=america 5.id:http://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=africa 6.id:http://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=asia`
Can someone help me to form a query to get only the 3 distinct urls here.I just want to get google.com,bing.com,duckduckgo.com .

Comment: Please note that the search term is different for all the records.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well can text the syntax, but this should work. Just use a script to split your url string.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "urls": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "script" : "def path = doc['id'].value; int currentSplit = path.indexOf("//"); if (currentSplit > 0) { path = path.substring(currentSplit + 1); currentSplit = path.indexOf("/"); if (currentSplit > 0) { path = path.substring(0, currentSplit) } } return path"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The best practice should be to index the domain name on the document if you need this aggregation a lot :).